# Fixed number of columns with grid-auto-flow: column

Tags: css, css-grid

I need to make a grid layout that has exactly four columns and orders the elements down instead of right.  Here's my starting point:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}
.box:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
  <div class="box">9</div>
  <div class="box">10</div>
  <div class="box">11</div>
  <div class="box">12</div>
</div>
```

Expected output is

```
1  5  9
2  6  10
3  7  11
4  8  12
```

If a 13th element is added, either is acceptable:

```
1  6  11           1  6  10
2  7  12           2  7  11
3  8  13     or    3  8  12
4  9               4  9  13
5  10              5
```

If only three divs were present then I would expect

```
1  2  3
```

Using something besides `display: grid` is OK too, though I can't change the markup much.

Comment: you gave the case of 3 element and 12 elements and 13 elements, what about the other cases? how it should behave between 3 and 12?

Comment: See the 13 example.  It doesn't really matter so long as all three columns are filled (e.g. 4 down would be unacceptable, but 1 column of 2 rows + 2 columns of 1 row is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `column-count: 3;` instead of `display: grid` and add `display: inline-block` to the child elements.

```css
.wrapper {
  column-count: 3;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
  <div class="box">9</div>
  <div class="box">10</div>
  <div class="box">11</div>
  <div class="box">12</div>
  <div class="box">13</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works most excellent!  Only two complains: the case of four is a bit awkward (though I understand why) and that I can only give it a single upvote!

Comment: this is not a grid! if some item gets taller, it breaks the layout

Comment: @sKopheK Of course it's a grid, if you don't see it then you're doing something wrong. Also you seem to apply this solution to another issue. This solution only applies to what the OP asked for. If you use uneven grid sizes then of course it will break. Use `display: grid` if you use dynamic item sizes.

Comment: @Aedan if you prefer ducktyping then yes, but under the hood it's not :) however, i stand corrected, as i didn't read OP's last sentence that he'd accept even non-grid solution, which was not my case. gw

Comment: @Aedan Thanks for the awesome trick, it worked. I had to do 
display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr)); column-count: 3;

Comment: I am having the same problematic with a requirement to use grid. While this answer may work in OP's case, it does not solve the problematic in the title, that'll cost a downvote sorry :/

Comment: @Oddrigue Why the downvote? The OP clearly stated in the description that using something other than `display: grid` is okay. The up and down votes are in regards to the OPs questions and not to yourself. Just because he didn't fit all requirements into the title, doesn't make it a bad answer. What you are looking for does not work with `grid` unless you have a fixed numbers of items that you know in advance. `grid` is not designed to do that with an unknown amount of items, especially not with conditional requirements such as having it automatically go horizontal if only 3 items are present.

Comment: @Aedan My bad I didn't see that line. An edit in the title would be welcome though