# how to iterate a collection in a html table with limited (n) columns in a row using thymeleaf

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, thymeleaf

I am new to front end and using thymeleaf. I am looking for an approach to build a dynamic form. I am sending a map from controller to front end (html), I am able to display the values of my map using  below code with thymeleaf attributes

```
<tr class="row" th:each="element : ${elementMap}">
    <td th:text="${element.key}"></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id=${element.keyth:name=${element.key} th:value="${element.value}" /><br>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I need to display 4 columns in a row. Or If converting above Map to ArrayList is it possible to allow 4 columns in a row. But when I use `th:each && th:text` for iterating content of Arraylist how to mention 4 columns in a row  (Any css style would be available)? Is there any other approach available to fix this ?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question, would you like to iterate the columns through `th:each`? because you are iterating the lines..

Comment: right now thymeleaf provides `th:each` to iterate collections. But I want to limit the number of columns in a row. How to handle it ? If need to use `th:each`  I cannot iterate 2 key value pairs from hahs map. If I go with ArrayList  how to set number of columns to 4 ?

Comment: "_I need to display 4 columns in a row_" - I am not sure what this means. Do you mean you want to keep only the first 4 values in your collection, and throw away everything else? Or do you want to force a new row after every 4th item in the current row? What is _wrong_ with the way you are currently displaying your items (since that seems to work)? Can you _show_ us what you want the end-result HTML to look like (instead of only _describing_ it)?

Comment: You mention you want to build a "dynamic form" but you show us what appears to be part of a HTML table. What is the relationship between your form and this table? Have you considered using a CSS grid with a [fixed number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62524831/12567365), instead of an HTML table? Would that meet your needs?

Answer (score -1):

on your page you are iterating one line for each `element`

the columns are the `td` tags, which according to the code you informed are two columns per line (key and value).

but if you want to limit the number of columns, you can use css, but by the structure of your code, you have dynamic lines (1 line for each element of the list) and you only have two columns per line.

if the problem is too many columns, you can only put up to 4 `td` tags